# Locating a dependent hotfix, should we close this quesiton or re-write it?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-close

So, I voted to close the question [Locating a dependent hotfix (80451)](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/284/locating-a-dependent-hotfix-80451) as has one other person.

After doing so I started to wonder if the better approach would be to rewrite the question as 'How do I locate a specific hotfix for Tridion?' and create an answer basically containing the content of Frank's comment 'You will have to contact Customer Support for this one. It is not a question that the community can answer, just the SDL Tridion folks'

It seems like if the question was re-written as such it would be a good community wiki question.

Does it make more sense to take this approach instead of closing this question?

Comment: +1 I agree about rewriting the question (rather than closing it).  This would allow answers on the correct approach for attaining and managing hotfixes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, I saw that one and was also quite surprised to see that as a question here. Is it just because you *may* get an answer faster here? Or is it perhaps because you don't know how to contact SDL Support, so you check here?

I agree it should be closed (and also voted to close it). Even if we do know how to get that hotfix, this is clearly the scope of action of Customer Support, not the community.

Comment: Yes, this doesn't seem like a function of *this* community. See http://meta.tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/12/will-the-tridion-forum-be-closed-once-we-go-public/25#25

Answer (score 3):

As I argued on the thread that Robert referenced, if the product is broken and has been fixed, then an answer that sends people to support is a good, effective one.

Comment: I think this question http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/515/duplicate-published-to-entries and Siva's answer is a good example of what you are talking about Dominic.

Comment: Exactly. What makes this kind of answer even more useful is that 1) support don't routinely tell us all about breakage, and 2) the questioner may need help to interpret their symptoms as the product being broken